# Capturar ID Do Input

Tags: php, html, mysql

Galera alguém sabe como eu faço pra capturar o id de um input e enviar para o banco da dados?

**EXEMPLO**

Tenho esse input:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="adicional" id="Leite Ninho" value="2.00">
```

Ele tem o name que eu vou usar pra chama-lo o value que eu uso pra somar, e o id que eu quero que exiba na tabela quando eu realizar o insert.

Alguem sabe como faço isso?

Comment: Esse input está dentro de um form?

Comment: Sim está dentro de um form

Comment: Vai ter que usar javascript para pegar ele e enviar para o php ... ou concatenar no value por um delimitador e dar um `explode()` no php.

Comment: Não, mano. Se liga... a tabela na base de dados já insere um **ID** automático se você configurar o `auto_increment`.

Comment: Valeu, certinho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[name=adicional]").attr("id")
```

se vc tiver vários checkboxes

```
$("input[name=adicional]").each(function(){

//var ou array 
$(this).attr("id");

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar Ajax com jQuery:

```
var field = $("input[name=adicional]");//Pega o seu campo

$.ajax("pagina.php", {
    "type": "POST",
    "data": {
        "id": field.attr("id"), //Envia o id
        "adicional": field.val() //Envia o valor
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
}).fail(function(a, b) {
    alert(b);
});
```

O PHP deve ser algo como:

```
<?php
$id    = $_POST['id'];
$valor = $_POST['adicional'];
```

No entanto se tem pouco conhecimento de ajax e tem urgencia em entregar o projeto, então recomendo fazer por html puro assim:

```
<input type="hidde" name="adiciona-id" value="Leite Ninho">
<input type="checkbox" name="adicional" value="2.00">
```

O PHP deve ser algo como:

```
<?php
$id    = $_POST['adiciona-id'];
$valor = $_POST['adicional'];
```

Não sei como esta o seu código html e nem o php, pois isto você não colocou na pergunta, respondi o que esta dentro do que foi perguntado, mas acredito que independente do código a lógica aqui se aplica a "quase qualquer lugar".

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma possível sem usar função `attr()` é:

```
$(":checkbox").each(function(){
    alert( this.id )
});
```

Ou se for só um elemento:

```
alert( $(":checkbox")[0].id )
```

O alert é ilustrativo.